# My custom Angular Component is showing one loop of data per screen in mat-tab

Tags: angular, angular-material, tabs

I have created a component which has **hukamnama-sahib.component.html** file as below:

```
<body *ngFor="let dataitem of HukamnamaSahibList">
  <h4>
    <span class="gurmukhi">{{dataitem.line.gurmukhi.unicode}}</span><br>
    <span class="punjabitranslation">{{dataitem.line.translation.punjabi.default.unicode}}</span><br>
    <span class="englishtranslation">{{dataitem.line.translation.english.default}}</span>
  </h4>
</body>
```

And the **app.component.html** looks as below:

```
<div class="container">

  <mat-tab-group preserveContent>
    <mat-tab label="First">
      <app-hukamnama-sahib></app-hukamnama-sahib>  // here, I have added the component
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Second"> <app-other-hukamnama></app-other-hukamnama> </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>


</div>
```

On loading the application, it looks as below (See the red-line area, it is blank. when I scroll to next, then comes the data for second loop (refer to 2nd screenshot)):

[image: data of first loop]

[image: data of second loop]

Please help me overcome this.

Comment: change `<body>` in your component to `<main>` or some other element. Also notice you are `ngFor` this element, so you are creating 1 body per element. If you use another html element, with different styles, this should work. Chainging it might not solve it, but this looks as a css issue and having a body inside a body is not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using a tag body, please replace div